# Extremely slow Sequelize PostGis query with ST_DistanceSphere

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

So I'm using Sequelize to query for items within a certain radius, i.e:

```
const radius = 10000 // metres

const location = sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${longitude} ${latitude})')`)
const distance = sequelize.fn('ST_DistanceSphere', sequelize.col('item.coordinates'), location)

console.time("test")

const nearbyItems = await models.Item.findAll({
    limit: 20,
    where: sequelize.where(distance, { [Op.lte]: radius }),
})

const response = []

console.timeEnd("test")
```

But this query takes neary 7 seconds to run (on a database with around 100 items in it). This seems bizarrely slow - can anyone see any issues with the code above that'd result in it being so slow? Is there a faster alternative anyone knows about?

Comment: How complicated are the geometries?

Comment: Just basic lat/lng points for each item. Or do you mean how precise are they?

Comment: Do you have a special index on geometry field?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not too sure. I attempted to add one in a migration with `queryInterface.addIndex('items', ['coordinates'])`, but I'm unclear if it did anything - I'm no expert with indices...

Comment: You should figure out the SQL statement generated, its execution plan and the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements. Then you can get help.

Comment: For 100 points, it should take no time. However when you will have more points it will be an issue, because the distance has to be computed for every row then filtering is done. You could instead use `st_dwithin` using geography instead of geometry, and with a spatial index on the geography

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to create a proper index on geometry column like this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_items_coordinates
  ON items
  USING GIST (coordinates);
```

See [PostGIS indexing](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html)